# I suddenly can't import functions from python packages in the same working directory as the python script I am running?

Tags: python, import

so I have the following path for some python scripts:

```
bin/
    main.py
    separate_hands.py
```

Inside the main.py module, I try to import a function that I define inside separate_hands.py like this:

```
from separate_hands import some_function
```

Where some_function is a function inside separate_hands.py. The above used to work just fine, but suddenly, I am getting an import error saying:

```
from separate_hands import some_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'separate_hands'
```

And in other places I am now getting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'detect_empty_seat' from 'step8_detect_empty_seat.detect_empty_seat'
```

Which definitely worked before.

I am so confused by this. Any ideas what could be causing this? I swear it was working before.

I don't get why it isn't recognising separate_hands as a python module...